# decipher this postgresql syntax?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query in an excel file that I inherited from the previous user/creator of the tool. The external connection is to a `PostgreSQL` database. Here's the line of script that I need to decipher so that I can hopefully adjust the date range for the query:

with

```
icon_date as (select max(icon.date::date)/* '1/1/2014'::date*/ as icon_date from pmm.icon)
```

...

pmm is the schema and .icon is the table name

My specific question is what this part means:

> /* '1/1/2014'::date*/

I have no clue what surrounding a date::data type with `/*  */` would do in the first part of the query. Any ideas? I can post more of query if that would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a comment and it will be ignored.

There are (at least) two ways to put comments into SQL:

1. everything after `--` until end of line
2. everything between `/*` and `*/` (even spanning lines)

My guess is that this is code left over from testing, where instead of the max you would select some fixed date (because it is faster, or data was missing).